# Error creating FlatFileItemWriter bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

When I call my batch program I get a null pointer exception on this line:

```
String fileName = ((Map<String, MccFtpFile>) ec.get(AbstractSetupTasklet.BATCH_FTP_FILES)).get("scacFile").getLocalFile();
```

Here is the entire class

```
 // Writer
        @Bean(name = "clf010Writer")
        @StepScope
        public FlatFileItemWriter<Clf010Item> clfWriter(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext}") Map<Object, Object> ec, //
                @Qualifier("clf010LineAggregator") FormatterLineAggregator<Clf010Item> lineAgg) throws IOException {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            String fileName = ((Map<String, MccFtpFile>) ec.get(AbstractSetupTasklet.BATCH_FTP_FILES)).get("scacFile").getLocalFile();
            //Ensure the file can exist.
            PrintWriter fos = getIoHarness().getFileOutputStream(fileName);
            fos.close();
            FlatFileItemWriter<Clf010Item> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
            writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(fileName));
            writer.setLineAggregator(lineAgg);
            return writer;
        }
```

I can't seem to figure out the problem. My guess is it's looking for a file it can't find? If anyone has some insight or information I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: You are trying to get the file from the job execution context in the writer. Which component is adding this info to the execution context? Is there a previous step adding it to the job execution context? You need to make sure this info is in the execution context before the writer is invoked.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Thank you for the insight, I'll dig in and see what I come up with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize, but in my setup tasklet I needed to declare a new ftp file :) thanks for the help